# Can someone find out if an email is forwarded to internal address

Tags: email

I have my own domain and I've set up email forwarding from mail sent to that domain to an email provider I use.

For example:
My domain: `site.com`
Email provider I use: `mail.com`

At domain provider, I've set up MX, TXT, CNAME DNS records provided by the email provider
At email provider, I've set up an address to receive mail: `mybox@site.com`

My question is: is it possible, given that someone knows `mybox@site.com` email, to somehow find out that I actually use `mail.com`?

Comment: On an email reply they might see your `mail.com` email gateway in the headers, but unless read receipts are enabled I don't think they can see anything on an email that they send to you.

Comment: Do you send from your site.com mail server, or the mail.com mail server (regardless of whether you're sending as mybox.site.com)? If it's the latter, then if the recipient checked the mail headers of the message then they would see mail.com as the originating server.

Comment: Yes.  I use Mail.com for most of my emails.  I am the recipient, and in the Headers, both mail.com and my own email ISP show up all the time.

Comment: Wouldnt this be apparent just by them scrutinizing the publucly accessible DNS records?

Comment: Could be, but the mail suppliers are readily available in the headers in my own emails.